# Cassandra - Nodetool Status shows "Owns as ?"

Tags: cassandra, datastax

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.30.27.172  202.52 KiB  1            ?       2300ea95-9114-4c03-819e-2c738de50824  rack1
UN  10.30.27.173  205.97 KiB  1            ?       d35063fe-2e81-4ab0-95ec-7024c9606b51  rack1
UN  10.30.27.171  222.02 KiB  1            ?       0f96a91b-77fb-4d49-ae87-ad9f61facb6b  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

I created a sample Keyspace and some tables under it. I can see records on other nodes. 
Why Owns show "?", How the data got split over cluster.

Answer (score 7):

This is the expected behaviour. Nodetool status uses the **Owns** column to indicate the effective percentage of the token range owned by the nodes. Because different keyspaces have different replication strategies, nodetool is not able to calculate a meaningful ownership percentage.

If you wish to see the ownership percentage, you can do that by simple adding the keyspace to the nodetool command:

```
nodetool status mykeyspace

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                            Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  rack1
UN  127.0.0.2  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  rack1
UN  127.0.0.3  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   49578bf1-728f-438d-b1c1-d8dd644b6f7f  rack1
```

Comment: I have Music key space having two tables and 4-5 rows. When I execute  "nodetool status mykeyspace" it throws "Error: The keyspace, does not exist" 
This is weird for me. I can see tables and data on all other nodes though Can you explain me in detail

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
nodetool status music
```

Comment: I did the same but says "Error: The keyspace Music, does not exist"

Comment: Then go to Cqlsh and do: DESCRIBE keyspaces;

Comment: Can you post the result here? This will show you all available keyspaces

Comment: Capitalization?